# How to find a random item that has no rows in a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have an Item model and a Flag model.  Item `has_many` Flags.  Flags `belong_to` Item.  Flag has the attributes `item_id`, `user_id`, and `reason`.  I need a way to find a random pending item that is not flagged.  I am using `enum` for pending status.

I believe I can find a random pending item that is flagged with:

```
@pending_item = Item.pending.joins(:flags).order("RANDOM()").first
```

but how can I find a random pending item that is not flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` with `not exists` to get `Item`s without `Flag`s:

```
@pending_item = Item.pending.
  where("not exists (select 1 from flags where flags.item_id = items.id)").
  order("RANDOM()").first
```

Side note: `order("RANDOM()").first` is not efficient if there are many `Item`s that meet the criteria. This will probably be more efficient for a large table:

```
unflagged_pending_items = Item.pending.
  where("not exists (select 1 from flags where flags.item_id = items.id)")
@pending_item = unflagged_pending_items.offset(rand unflagged_pending_items.count).first
```

Alternatively, if the first query isn't too slow and you don't need a different random item every time, you could just cache the result for a while.

Comment: If I have a very large amount of pending items is `.order("RANDOM()").first` an efficient way to find a random one?

Comment: Oh, I'd meant to say something about that. I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, wether it's better to use a sub-select or not. I prefer to use ids and foreign keys where I can use it.

```
# initialize my instance variable to have it in the view always
@pending_item = nil

# get an array with all flagged item ids
flagged_item_ids = Flag.group(:item_id).pluck(:item_id)

# search for an unflagged item, if there are item ids in the array only, 
# because the statement could return a flagged item with an empty array in the condition  
if flagged_item_ids > 0
  @pending_item = Item.pending.where.not(id: flagged_item_ids).order("RANDOM()").first
end

@pending_item
# => an unflagged random item or nil
```

Keep in mind that the array `flagged_item_ids` could hold a huge amount of flagged item ids. This can consume a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

```
Item.pending.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id, item_id
                                      FROM flags
                                    ) AS temp
                                    ON temp.item_id = items.id")
            .where('temp.id = null')
            .order("RANDOM()")
            .first
```

So if we use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `temp.id` will equal `null` if that item is not flagged.

**Solution #2**

```
Item.pending.where("id NOT IN ( SELECT item_id FROM flags )")
            .order("RAMDOM()")
            .first
```

This is clear, we find an item which wasn't flagged.