# Most efficient way to find random item not present in join table and without repeating previous random item

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, random, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have an Item model and a Flag model.  Item `has_many` Flags.  Flags `belong_to` Item.  Flag has the attributes `item_id`, `user_id`, and `reason`.  I am using `enum` for pending status.  I need the most efficient way to get an item that doesn't exist in the flags table because I have a VERY large table.  I also need to make sure that when a user clicks to generate another random item, it will not repeat the current random item back to back.  It would be OK to repeat any time afterwards, just not back to back.

This is what I have so far:

```
def pending_item
  @pending_items = Item.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags ON flags.item_id = items.id").
                   where("items.user_id != #{current_user.id} and flags.id is null")
  @pending_item = @pending_badges.offset(rand @pending_badges.count).first
end
```

Is there a more efficient way than this?

And how can I make sure there are no back to back repeats of the same `pending_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is the fastest way to do it in the database I know of (which is why I gave it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37211384/634576)). Many other Stack Overflow posts discuss ways to efficiently select random rows from tables; there are more efficient methods if you're selecting from an entire table, but they don't apply when you're selecting a random result from a query whose results can be different every time.

If performance is critical, it would be much faster to do it in memory.

- The first time you need to pick a random pending item for a given user, select all of the user's pending items from the database and store them in the Rails cache. (This only works if there's a reasonable number of pending items per user.)
- Each time you need to pick a random pending item for a given user, get the full list from the cache and pick a random member with `.sample` or whatever.
- Here's the tricky part: to keep the cache consistent, every time you do anything that could change a user's full list of pending items (including something like adding a new flag type), you'll need to invalidate the cache entry.

This is a lot of effort, so you really have to want to do it.

Regarding avoiding repeats, the only way to do that reliably is to store the last pending item displayed and exclude it from your query

```
def pending_item
  @pending_items = UserItem.
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags ON flags.item_id = items.id").
    where("items.user_id != ?", current_user.id).
    where("flags.id is null").
    where("items.id != ?", previous_shown_item_id)
  @pending_item = @pending_badges.offset(rand @pending_badges.count).first
end
```

or, if you do the random selection in memory, exclude the last shown pending item when you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Does chaining `.where`'s together results in multiple queries and slow things down?  I thought it did so that's why the code in my question here is slightly different from your other answer.  `Item.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags ON flags.item_id = items.id").where("items.user_id != #{current_user.id} and flags.id is null")` vs `Item.where("user_id != #{current_user.id}").where("not exists (select 1 from flags where flags.item_id = items.id)")`

Comment: No, multiple wheres become a single query with ands. Using multiple wheres makes it easier to let ActiveRecord do the string substitution for you, since it's easier to see which variable goes with which `?`.